# rich:componentControl (RichFaces 3 to 4 migration)

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, contextmenu

In our web project we were using rich:contextMenu and rich:componentControl. After migrating to jsf2 (richFaces 4) all the pages with those components starting throwing npe even after following rules for migration (for contextMenu, richItem and componentControl).

Code for contextMenu is:

```
<rich:contextMenu attached="false" id="contextMenu" hideDelay="400" disableDefaultMenu="false">
      <rich:menuItem action="#{bean.action}" icon="/images/icon.png" label="label">
        <a4j:param assignTo="#{bean.id}" value="{id}" />
      </rich:menuItem>
    </rich:contextMenu>
```

componentControl is located inside of a rich:dataTable for whose rows I want contextMenu to be shown. Code for componentControl is:

```
<rich:componentControl event="onRowClick" target="contextMenu" operation="show">
  <f:param value="#{row.id}" name="id" />
</rich:componentControl>
```

Stack trace is as follows:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.richfaces.taglib.ComponentControlHandler.processNextHandler(ComponentControlHandler.java:96)
at org.richfaces.taglib.ComponentControlHandler.processNestedTags(ComponentControlHandler.java:64)
at org.richfaces.taglib.ComponentControlHandler.apply(ComponentControlHandler.java:57)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
at org.richfaces.view.facelets.html.BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.applyNextHandler(BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.java:53)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:196)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
at org.richfaces.view.facelets.html.BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.applyNextHandler(BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.java:53)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:196)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
at org.richfaces.view.facelets.html.BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.applyNextHandler(BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.java:53)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:196)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:107)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:178)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:395)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:366)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:112)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:107)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:178)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:395)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:366)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:112)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ViewHandler.apply(ViewHandler.java:180)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
at org.richfaces.view.facelets.html.BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.applyNextHandler(BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.java:53)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:196)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:305)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:364)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:343)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:155)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:305)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:364)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:343)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:155)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:149)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:838)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:100)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.mpvo.univerzitet.SessionExpiredRedirectFilter.doFilter(SessionExpiredRedirectFilter.java:26)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.mpvo.rootgen.TransactionViewFilter.doFilter(TransactionViewFilter.java:35)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:304)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Is there anything else that needs to be changed in order for this to work?

Comment: Having just been through all this my recommendation is to migrate *away* from RichFaces towards something that is properly managed and has some regard for existing users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components in RF 4 that handle events accept lowercase names without `on`, in your case:

```
<rich:componentControl event="rowclick" target="contextMenu" operation="show">
```